# Is it possible to use Chaos Monkey Spring Boot w/o SB Actuator?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-boot-chaos-monkey

I am working on a project and we want to implement some Chaos Testing. We want to use Spring Boot Chaos Monkey however we are unable to use one of the hard dependencies of  Spring Boot Actuator (Jackson Databind to be specific). It seems implementing SB Actuator is not an option. We cannot access Chaos Monkey via JMX. It must be HTTP.

- Is it possible to hit Chaos Monkey monkey endpoints w/o SB Actuator?

Comment: I'm not seeing anything in the documentation that says actuator is required. Where are you seeing this? Did you add chaos monkey to your app and it didn't work?

Comment: Yes. The documentation describes their endpoints as "Actuator endpoints". The endpoints did not work w/o Actuator. We even created a simple "Hello World" microservice, and this worked, but only w/ Actuator

Comment: Per the [Documentation](https://codecentric.github.io/chaos-monkey-spring-boot/latest/), the Chaos Monkey `management.endpoint.*` seem to presume Spring Boot Actuator.  Q: Is SB Actuator itself the problem?  Or is the main problem that it uses Jackson Databind?

Comment: Most spring-boot components have optional actuator endpoints. They only become relevant if you actually include Actuator in your project. I'm asking ... _did you try it?_

Comment: Yes we tried it.

Comment: And? what happened? Because it's [listed as an optional dependency](https://github.com/codecentric/chaos-monkey-spring-boot/blob/main/chaos-monkey-spring-boot/pom.xml#L118-L122) in chaos-monkey itself.

Comment: all endpoints returned a 404

Comment: @paulsm4 The problem is Jackson DB hard dependency on SB Actuator

Comment: Q: so your problem isn't with SB Actuator per se, but with the fact that SB Actuator brings in Jackson Databind, correct?  Q: (out of curiosity): what's the issue with bringing Jackson Databind into your project?  Why is this a "problem"?  Q: Have you considered "injecting" a "mock" implementation of Jackson Databind (for example, like you'd mock a "service" for a JUnit test)?  I believe Spring Boot would support this (at least in theory), but I can't give you any guidance without a) knowing many more details, and b) trying it out in my own lab...

Comment: I believe the issue w/ Databind is a security related issue but really it comes from the higher ups and I don't have specifics. I have not considered using a mock but will look into that